# @angular/fire where exists

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I'm getting a firestore's document with the 'where'.My goal is to know if this one already exists (like : is this pseudo in one collection) but with uid.

```
 var request = this.ms.afs.collection('users', ref => ref.where('uuidsocial', '==', uid)).get().subscribe(users => { 
      if(users.size > 0){
        console.log("exists");
        console.log(users.size);
      }else{
        console.log("doesn't exist");
      }
    });
```

Haven't worked, always returning 1, and I'm sure it's not the right code now, tried a lot of things.
Thanks a lot

Comment: are you using AngularFirestore ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
var docRef = this.ms.afs.collection("users").doc(uid);
docRef.get().then((doc) => {
    if (doc.exists) {
        console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
    } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

See documentation here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Also do this with a query:

```
this.ms.afs.collection('users', (ref) => ref.where('uuidsocial', '==',uid))
    .get()
    .subscribe(user => { if(user.size >= 0) ...do smthg })
```

Comment: Yes, but i'm using' where '^^

Comment: @nonoom see my upodated answer and let me know

Answer (score 0):

#### Update

As pointed out in a comment, apparently `users` is a [`QuerySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot). You could try `users.empty`, though I don't see any reason why `users.size` wouldn't work. My guess is that, for whatever reason, that collection always has at least one user with `uuidsocial === ${whatever your test uid is}`. I'd try `console.log(users)` to see what you're getting back.

<s>I think you want `users.length`. Javascript arrays don't have a `size` property.</s>

```js
var request = this.ms.afs.collection('users', ref => ref.where('uuidsocial', '==', uid)).get().subscribe(users => { 
  if (users.length > 0){
    console.log("exists");
    console.log(users.length);
  } else {
    console.log("doesn't exist");
  }
});
```

Comment: Hello, when I try your code, I'm getting : ```Property 'length' does not exist on type 'QuerySnapshot'.ts(2339)```

Comment: @nonoom ah, I had (incorrectly) assumed that `users` was an array.